# SQL Server Monitoring Tools

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, monitoring

Can anyone recommend a good SQL server Monitoring Tool?
One which will provide info on, server space usage, CPU usage , expensive queries run etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommendations for MS SQL Server monitoring software or service?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4331/recommendations-for-ms-sql-server-monitoring-software-or-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using SQL Spy 9.0 - Cost is free
I also use Utility Explorer from Microsoft - Cost free

Answer (score 4):

I've voted to close this, because it's essentially a poll question, and there isn't a possible "right answer." You should be evaluating the vendors' offerings to see which product best suits your requirements and budget. Nobody can tell you which product will do that best.

The major vendors you want to investigate are:

- [SQL Sentry](https://www.sentryone.com/products/sentryone-platform/sql-sentry/sql-server-performance-monitoring)
- Quest [FogLight](http://www.quest.com/foglight/) / [SpotLight](http://www.quest.com/spotlight-on-sql-server-enterprise/)
- [Confio Ignite](http://www.confio.com/performance/sql-server/ignite/)
- [RedGate SQL Monitor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/)
- [Microsoft System Center Operations Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/datacenter-management.aspx)
- [Idera Diagnostic Manager](http://www.idera.com/SQL-Server/SQL-diagnostic-manager/)

They all have evaluation versions so you can test them out. In addition to feature sets you'll want to baseline your workloads and check the additional overhead each monitoring solution adds - no monitoring is 100% free.

Comment: Hi Aaron, at my old job we used Quest PerfMon (whatever the name was prior to Foglight) which supposedly didn't degrade performance like Sql Server Profiler, do these other tools act in a similar manner [to foglight]? If you have experience in any/all of these, are there any metrics you've seen that can show the degradation in performance based on the tool used for monitoring to see how they compare?

Comment: SQL Sentry is the only company I know of (and I'll confess, I haven't checked lately) that has actually documented the overhead you should expect to see given typical settings and a benchmark workload (I actually wrote it). You can [download the Word document here](http://downloads.sqlsentry.com/downloads/SQLSentryOverheadAnalysis.doc). Then feel free to ask any of the other vendors if they have published something similar. In any case, they all have trial versions, so you're not going to get a better idea of overhead than installing them and trying with your workload in your environment.